# Code pattern equivalent to chained if/elseif on blocking conditions in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, if-statement, asynchronous, callback

I want to write in Node.JS the equivalent of the following synchronous code:

```
function(param)
{
    if(condition1(param))     {f(param);}
    else if(condition2(param)){g(param);}
    else if(condition3(param)){h(param);}
    ...
}
```

Where the verification of the conditions is possibly doing some database, filesystem or even http I/O; so should not be run in such a synchronous code.

Simple but dirty solution: one can chain callbacks as in the answer to that question [How to write a non-blocking if statement in Node JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419220/how-to-write-a-non-blocking-if-statement-in-node-js)

But when the number of conditions are high it becomes easily unreadable and hard to modify (eg. to change the order of the conditions).

Is there a nice pattern that can be used to keep such a code neat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to check out the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: Thanks, using the function async.series([f,g,h]) (and putting the condition inside the functions) is the neat syntax I was looking for.
(new account I can't upvote)

Answer (score 2):

The [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library has a function that can help with this, [`series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series). Here is an equivalent to your code using `series`:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        if (condition1(param)) {
            f(param);
        } else { callback(null); }
    },
    function(callback) {
        if (condition2(param)) {
            g(param);
        } else { callback(null); }
    },
    function(callback) {
        if (condition3(param)) {
            h(param);
        } else { callback(null); }
    }
]);
```

(This answer just adds more detail to [this answer mentioning async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414755/578288) and [your comment mentioning `series`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405837/code-pattern-equivalent-to-chained-if-elseif-on-blocking-conditions-in-node-js#comment30526826_20414755).)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have used [Streamline](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) with great success in my (admittedly small) node.js projects. As you can see from their page, it allows you to transform code like

```
function archiveOrders(date, cb) {
  db.connect(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    conn.query("select * from orders where date < ?", [date], function(err, orders) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      helper.each(orders, function(order, next) {
        conn.execute("insert into archivedOrders ...", [order.id, ...], function(err) {
          if (err) return cb(err);
          conn.execute("delete from orders where id=?", [order.id], function(err) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            next();
          });
        });
      }, function() {
        console.log("orders have been archived");
        cb();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

into

```
function archiveOrders(date, _) {
  var conn = db.connect(_);
  conn.query("select * from orders where date < ?", [date], _).forEach_(_, function(_, order) {
    conn.execute("insert into archivedOrders ...", [order.id, ...], _);
    conn.execute("delete from orders where id=?", [order.id], _);
  });
  console.log("orders have been archived");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you may want to check the other answer about the async lib. It was simpler for me to understand what is going on.
Would upvote though if I could...